# HTML5 and ARIA Semantics: DHTML Sub Navigation

Tags: html, seo, accessibility, nav

I have a **one-page website** where the user is presented with a **rows of tabs *(photos that are buttons)* that reveal new content.**

With accessibility and search-engine-friendliness in mind,

  ***What might be considered the best practice, semantically?***

Here's what I've figured:

```
<section class="fruits">
  <h1>Fruits</h1>
  <nav>
    <a data-article-class="banana"> 
      <p>Learn about <strong>Bananas</strong></p> </a>
    <a data-article-class="apple" class="is-selected"> 
      <p>Learn about <strong>Apples</strong></p> </a>
    <a data-article-class="pear">
      <p>Learn about <strong>Pears</strong></p> </a>
  </nav>
  <div>
    <article class="banana">
      <h1>The Banana</h1>
      <p>A long yellow fruit...</p>
    </article>
    <article class="apple is-selected">
      <h1>The Apple</h1>
      <p>A round red fruit...</p>
    </article>
    <article class="pear">
      <h1>The Pear</h1>
      <p>A funny-shaped green fruit...</p>
    </article>
  </div>
</section>
```

- When the user clicks one of the `<a>` tags, JavaScript places the `is-selected` class on the `<a>` and its corresponding `<article>`.
- The `<a>` tags would be styled with CSS to look like clickable images with the text visibly inside.
- The `is-selected` class represents which link and corresponding article is currently selected -- CSS will `display:none;` all articles, and then `display:block;` the article that has `is-selected`.

***To be precise,*** my questions are:

- Should I be using a `<nav>` element with inner `<a>` elements?
- Is it redundant to wrap the `<a>`s in a `<ul>`/`<li>` structure in this context?
- Is there a better way to semantically represent the relationship between the navigation and the articles for sections like these?

---

## Update:

@AlastairC's informative answer sent me in the right direction. Though, he suggested a more semantic nesting format, which is unfortunately incompatible with the `display:table-cell;`-based layout for this tabbing unit that I desire.

Based on Alastair's advice, I revised the markup in a community wiki answer using ARIA standards (to correlate the tabs with the content they control). I'm thinking I'll select Alastair's answer, but if anybody could comment on or improve the community wiki answer with the alternate markup, I'd very much appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that would work, but there might be a better overall HTML approach that gets a better result for less work. For accessibility (my specialist area) I would consider these requirements for this scenario:

1. Can some using a keyboard (but sees the screen) tab to the images and select them?
2. Can someone with mild-to-moderate visual impairment zoom in using browser controls and still see the content (that's probably more on the CSS side than the semantics though so I won't cover it here).
3. Can a screen reader user tell that there is more information to be had by selecting the picture, and find the information when it's selected.

There are two main ways I can think of to implement what you've described, and you have taken a 'tab' approach so far, where there are a set of controls at the top, and content underneath that shows the selected option.

The other way would be nesting, like this:

```
<section class="fruits">
  <h1>Fruits</h1>
  <ul>
    <li>
       <a data-article-class="banana"> 
         <p>Learn about <strong>Bananas</strong></p>
       </a>
       <div id="content-banana">
         <h2>The Banana</h2>
         <p>A long yellow fruit...</p>
       </div>
    </li>
    ...
  </ul>
</section>
```

And then you would need to position the visible content where you wish. I can't quite tell if that would work from the description (without a diagram), but it is usually feasible.

Either approach can fulfils the keyboard-only and zooming scenarios, but what you would need to do for screen readers varies considerably.

For the **tab approach** you would need to use [WAI-ARIA](http://www.w3.org/WAI/intro/aria) to set up the relationship between the controls and the content, and spend quite a bit of time manipulating keyboard controls (see [Tabs design pattern](http://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-practices/#tabpanel)). Otherwise when a screen reader user selects a picture, they have no idea where the content has appeared.

For the **nested approach** there is an intrinsic relationship setup by the DOM, so things are easier. 
A screen reader user would browse (generally 'arrow') down to an image and select it. I would recommend moving the keyboard focus to the new content when selected, so at the end of the function that shows the content you would add something like:

```
$('#content-banana').attr('tabindex', '-1').css('outline', 'none');
$('#content-banana').focus();
```

That makes the div focusable, removes the outline (which is not needed as you cannot 'tab' to it anyway), and sets the focus there. 
**NB:** It looks like you could combine the lines, but I've found that doesn't work reliably across screen readers.

Once finished reading, the screen reader user could simply arrow down to the next item and select that (or not), there is no issue of knowing where content is.

As for what tags to use, `<article>` isn't really suitable here unless there is quite a lot of content. It might be suitable for the whole item (replacing the `section`), but if it is not [aimed at being distributed/syndicated](http://html5doctor.com/the-article-element/) then section is fine.

I would lean towards using a list as the container, because it provides a way for screen reader users to skip the rest of the items if they are not interested. With the nested approach 'nav' isn't suitable at all. Even in the tab approach the W3C recommends a list and links for the tab controls.

Also, I *think* (but could be corrected) that having the image and content closer together in the source is good for SEO, as the image is more likely to be associated with the words near it.

NB: I should also point out that if the images are meaningful, they should be foreground images with suitable alt attributes.

Comment: On the `<nav>`, use of `display:table-cell;` is important for me to achieve a desired layout which I fear is not possible with the more semantic nesting you've suggested. ***Using your greatly appreciated guidance,*** I will produce an alternate answer utilizing the [**WAI-ARIA Tabpanel Technique**](http://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-practices/#tabpanel) you linked to, and then request your feedback. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

***Following @AlastairC's guidance,*** I've started this solution which includes the [WAI-ARIA Tab Panel Widget](http://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-practices/#tabpanel) stuff:

```
<!--( My Fruit Tabbing Widget )-->
<section class="fruits" role="application">
  <h1>Fruits</h1>

  <nav role="tablist"><ul> <!--( The Tabs )-->
    <li>
      <a id="fruit_tab_1" role="tab" 
       tabindex="1" aria-controls="fruit_content_1"> 
        <p>Learn about <strong>Bananas</strong></p> </a> </li>
    <li>
      <a id="fruit_tab_2" role="tab" 
       tabindex="2" aria-controls="fruit_content_2"> 
        <p>Learn about <strong>Apples</strong></p> </a> </li>
    <li>
      <a id="fruit_tab_3" role="tab" 
       tabindex="3" aria-controls="fruit_content_3">
        <p>Learn about <strong>Pears</strong></p> </a> </li>
  </ul></nav>

  <div role="tabpanel"> <!--( The Content )-->
    <section id="fruit_content_1" 
     role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="fruit_tab_1">
      <h1>The Banana</h1>
        <p>A long yellow fruit...</p> </section>
    <section id="fruit_content_2"
     role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="fruit_tab_2">
      <h1>The Apple</h1>
      <p>A round red fruit...</p> </section>
    <section id="fruit_content_3"
     role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="fruit_tab_3">
      <h1>The Pear</h1>
      <p>A funny-shaped green fruit...</p> </section>
  </div>

</section>

<!--( JavaScript will apply and manipulate 
  aria-hidden attributes on the section tabpanels, 
  and aria-selected on the tabs, as well as provide 
  basic CSS changes for showing or hiding content )-->
```

***If anyone can provide clarification or improvements:***

- Did I correctly implement ARIA above? I'm new to it. *I saw some official examples that included a ton of JavaScript for keyboard functionality which I choose to ignore.*
- I can't help but feel like `<nav>` may be appropriate for the tablist, as it seems logical to me that the tabs are a navigation block for the "fruits" section. Is this acceptable, permissible, discouraged, or unacceptable?
- Are `<a>` tags more appropriate than `<button>`s or otherwise?
- What about `tabindex`? Is this set up correctly? *I don't understand the `tabindex="-1"` business.*

***This answer is set as a community wiki in hopes that somebody like you may improve it.***

Comment: I suggest using one of the examples from http://accessibleculture.org/articles/2010/08/aria-tabs/ to start with, you really have to include the keyboard functionality for it to make sense. E.g. http://accessibleculture.org/research-files/aria-tabs/version2b.php To answer the questions: 1. No, the ARIA attributes should be applied through JS. Nav is not appropriate, see the example. You really need to read about tabindex  http://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-practices/#focus_tabindex